# Make entire Menu Item Clickable

Tags: html, css, web, menu

I seem to be having a problem with my CSS in making the entire menu item clickable, not just the text.
As you can see from the highlighted screenshot, the menu does not extend to 100% height of the div. As a result, only the text of the menu is clickable, not the whole box around it. How do I make the entire box clickable?
(Code Below)
[image: picture outlining problem]

```
#header
{
    background-color: black;


}
#header .menu
{
display: inline;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
position: relative;
text-transform:uppercase;



}


#header .menu ul{
display: inline-block;

}
#header .menu li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
width: auto;
color: white;
height: 100%;
position: relative;

}
#header .menu a{
display: block;
width: 100%
height: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-family: Helvetica;

}
#header .menu ul li a{
display: block;
}
#header .menu li a{
position: relative;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can i see your sample HTML and CSS code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of CSS

```
#header .menu
{
    display: inline;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
position: relative;
    text-align: center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

#header .menu li { display: inline; float:left; }

#header .menu li a
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #000;
font-family: Helvetica;
}

#header ul li a:hover
{
color: Yellow;
background-color: #000;
}
```

Here is a [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/1m4ghx6t/)

Comment: excellent work (upvote). It is the answer that he/she is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation ^_^